# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, adress = 0x0) while changing value of boolean

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, boolean, runtime-error

**What I'm trying to do**

---

In my app, I got a SQL-Lite Database for which I wrote some Methodes. The Callback of the Method is a Boolean. True = Could write the data, False = Could not write the data. The Code dosn't show any Error's in X-Code so I should be right.

**Question**

---

In my Method I define a Boolean and set it to Null. Afterwards I have an If-Clause, which check's if the data could be written into my db, and change the defined Boolean to true or false. Which throws me the Error:`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x0)`

The point is, I don't understand why this Error is coming along. Could you guys please tell me, what I'm doing wrong and how I can solve it. You'll find the Code down here:

**Code**

---

```
    - (BOOL *) createLogin:(NSInteger *)user_id
                   usr: (NSString *)username
                   pwd: (NSString *)password
                  date: (NSDate *)last_login{

    BOOL *returnvalue = NULL;

    self.ivo_db = [[ivo_database alloc] init];

    if((sqlite3_open_v2([[ivo_db getWritableDatabase] UTF8String], &sqldb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)){

    NSLog(@" %s Couldn't open writable database '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(sqldb), sqlite3_errcode(sqldb));

    }else{
        int userid = *user_id;
        NSString *sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO tbl_login (user_id, username, password, last_login) VALUES (%d,'%@','%@','%@')", userid, username, password, last_login];

    const char *putLoginData = [sqlString UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare(sqldb, putLoginData, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s SQLITE_ERROR while preparing Statement '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(sqldb), sqlite3_errcode(sqldb));
        *returnvalue = NO;
    }else{

    sqlite3_step(sqlStatement);
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);

    int lastInsert = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(sqldb);
    NSLog(@"lastinsertid:%d", lastInsert);
    sqlite3_close(sqldb);
    *returnvalue = YES;
    }
   }
    return returnvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BOOL *returnvalue = NULL;
/* ... */
*returnvalue = YES;
```

You first create a pointer to BOOL. You set the address it's pointing to to NULL. Then you try to set the value of the address it's pointing to to YES.

Or short: You try to write at adress 0x00. That won't work.

You want to use BOOL. The primitive type, without a pointer.

```
- (BOOL) createLogin:(NSInteger *)user_id
               usr: (NSString *)username
               pwd: (NSString *)password
              date: (NSDate *)last_login{
    BOOL returnValue = NO;
    /* ... */
    returnValue = YES;
    /* ... */
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Hey Matthias, this worked great, thx for explaining what was wrong! But now I got a yellow-pointed error: "Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'renturnvalue' returned", is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Try initialize Bool as False from Start.

and When you are changing values of variable do like returnvalue = YES;